# How can I fix the ElectronNET.CLI Cannot find module 'fs/promises'. Require stack error

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-packager, asp.net5, electron.net

I have an **ASP.NET 5** web application and I'm using **ElectronNET**. When I run the `electronize build /target win` command want to create electron application exe file and setup exe file, ElectronNET.CLI says;
[image]

and not creating application exe file and setup exe file. How can i fix this issue?

Comment: What version of node?

Comment: @Phix node version is v12.18.4

Answer (score 1):

OK I fixed the issue. I updated the node to version of 14.17.5